# Add an HTML area to a Winform Application

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm developping a books library application for my internship.
I have a GridView thats shows me the list of books I have in a database.
I want to add a feature that when I click on some book in the GridView to display me all it's informations like an HTML page, as in this picture.

[image]

How can I add this HTML area to my form, and how can I display Informations in it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `WebBrowser Class`

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/w290k23d.aspx

Your sample :

```
WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
browser.Url = new Uri("your Url");
```

Set content in webBrowser with    `browser.DocumentText`

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext.aspx

Comment: Okey thanks, but how can I display all the informations of some record when I click on it in the gridView.
this is the code I use to get a dataRow from the gridView:
row = gridView1.GetDataRow(gridView1.GetSelectedRows()[0]);

Comment: I'am happy to help you, you can use browser.DocumentText = htmlContent;